# mySQL and Date issue not inserting via PhpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting an error and can't seem to see what is wrong. The date I have tried with 'date' and slashes for 2017-04-30 and same error message which gets cut off at the end and can't tell.  I cannot get this to accept when going to the SQL tab in PhPMyAdmin these five records.  I am in school and this one is driving me nuts and have a deadline.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

NOTE: These are not real people etc...

```
INSERT INTO Employees(Employee_ID, Fname, Lname, Email, Salary, City, State, Hired Date) 
VALUES ('1','Joe','Smith','j.smith@gmail.com','55,000','Scottsdale','AZ',20170430),
('2', 'Linda', 'Smith', 'lsmith125@gmail.com', '35,000.00', 'Tempe', 'AZ', 20170505),
('3', 'Bob', 'Jones', 'bob.jones567@aol.com', '85,000.00', 'Gilbert', 'AZ', 20170415),
('4', 'Sally', 'Lugether', 'slugether1@gmail.com', '40,000.00', 'Scottsdale', 'AZ', 20170710),
('5', 'Gerry', 'Ferguson', 'gfergusonjur@yahoo.com', '95,000.00', 'Phoenix', 'AZ', 20170618)
```

Comment: White space in column names is a bad idea but if you must have whitespaces then enclose the column name in mysql's escape character ` (backtick). You might also read up on str_to_date.Mysql will automatically convert a string in the form 'yyyy-mm-dd' to a date field when inserting (amongst other  actions)

Comment: Can you tell us what the error message is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In there, I see 2 errors at simple view:

1- the name of the field date `Hired Date` cannot have a space.

2- the insert format of date is: `'yyyy-mm-dd'` (yes, the ' ' too).

Try on that way and let me know!